Can't visualize the validation error on flask web server
I am trying to show a validation error to the users when they try to sign up with an email or username that's already been taken.
However, despite the fact it works, but I can't see anything on the webpage when I run the web development server.
Here is the Python code for the validation error:
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from flaskblog.models import User


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if email:
            raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')

But even if the outline is red, I don't see the message:

I'm not sure if it's useful, but here's also the layout.html code I use for generic rendering of pages:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }} </title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for category, message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>


Please show us your code that renders the form in the template. Are you using form.errors as shown in this example?

Everything looks alright here, but you might be missing an argument when you render this template. Make sure that everything is being imported over there correctly. & By any chance can you share the rendered template code where the template gets rendered?

You can iterate over the errors attribute of either the form or the field to display the error message.
